# do_compile error while running bitbake on poky

Tags: yocto, bitbake

iam using poky to build a BSP for my imxsabreauto board. i got the following error. please help me on this.

error log:

NOTE: Preparing runqueue
NOTE: Executing SetScene Tasks
NOTE: Executing RunQueue Tasks
ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /home/viswanath/SabreAuto_error/build-wayland/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/busybox/1.22.1-r32/temp/log.do_compile.15410)

ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/viswanath/SabreAuto_error/build-wayland/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/busybox/1.22.1-r32/temp/log.do_compile.15410

| DEBUG: SITE files ['endian-little', 'bit-32', 'arm-common', 'common-linux', 'common-glibc', 'arm-linux', 'arm-linux-gnueabi', 'common']

| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile

| grep: .config: No such file or directory

| cp: cannot stat '.config': No such file or directory

| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.

| ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /home/viswanath/SabreAuto_error/build-wayland/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/busybox/1.22.1-r32/temp/log.do_compile.15410)

ERROR: Task 2086 (/home/viswanath/SabreAuto_error/sources/poky/meta/recipes-core/busybox/busybox_1.22.1.bb, do_compile) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 2014 tasks of which 16 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.
Waiting for 0 running tasks to finish:

Summary: 1 task failed:
  /home/viswanath/SabreAuto_error/sources/poky/meta/recipes-core/busybox/busybox_1.22.1.bb, do_compile
Summary: There was 1 ERROR message shown, returning a non-zero exit code.

bitbake file:

require busybox.inc

PR = "r32"

SRC_URI = 
"http://www.busybox.net/downloads/busybox-${PV}.tar.bz2;name=tarball \

```
       file://get_header_tar.patch \
       file://busybox-appletlib-dependency.patch \
       file://busybox-udhcpc-no_deconfig.patch \
       file://find-touchscreen.sh \
       file://busybox-cron \
       file://busybox-httpd \
       file://busybox-udhcpd \
       file://default.script \
       file://simple.script \
       file://hwclock.sh \
       file://mount.busybox \
       file://syslog \
       file://syslog-startup.conf \
       file://syslog.conf \
       file://busybox-syslog.default \
       file://mdev \
       file://mdev.conf \
       file://umount.busybox \
       file://defconfig \
       file://busybox-syslog.service.in \
       file://busybox-klogd.service.in \
       file://fail_on_no_media.patch \
       file://run-ptest \
       file://inetd.conf \
       file://inetd \
       file://login-utilities.cfg \
       file://0001-build-system-Specify-nostldlib-when-linking-to-.o-fi.patch \
       file://recognize_connmand.patch \
       file://busybox-cross-menuconfig.patch \
```

"

SRC_URI[tarball.md5sum] = "337d1a15ab1cb1d4ed423168b1eb7d7e"
SRC_URI[tarball.sha256sum] = "ae0b029d0a9e4dd71a077a790840e496dd838998e4571b87b60fed7462b6678b"

EXTRA_OEMAKE += "V=1 ARCH=${TARGET_ARCH} CROSS_COMPILE=${TARGET_PREFIX} SKIP_STRIP=y"

do_install_ptest () {

```
    cp -r ${B}/testsuite ${D}${PTEST_PATH}/

    cp ${B}/.config      ${D}${PTEST_PATH}/

    ln -s /bin/busybox   ${D}${PTEST_PATH}/busybox
```

}

inherit autotools gettext

Comment: Did you read [host requirements](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#required-packages-for-the-host-development-system) and [Freescale BSP instructions](https://github.com/Freescale/fsl-community-bsp-platform)?

Comment: @Nayfe, "read the docs" answers are often unhelpful, unless you take time to point out specific aspects of the docs to focus the person on a particular aspect. Yocto is a substantially large project, and has many sources for documentation.

Answer (score 1):

the error seems to there is no "`.config file`".
if you need `p-test` click the link  [p-test yocto](https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/Ptest)
for busybox see the link [busybox.bb](http://cgit.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/tree/meta/recipes-core/busybox/)